# Securing access to uploaded images/files (Angular, NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, upload, multer

wondering what the modern paradigm is for securing upload images/files.

In other words, I have a website which requires authentication. Once a user logs in they can upload files/images which they can later access.

I'm using multer for the file upload, so a couple questions:

1) Should I be storing files in a database (MongoDB) or in folders? Pros and cons? Security considerations?

2) Assuming the answer to #1 is "folders", how do I practically control access to (i.e. authorization) to those files. In other words, if a user upload file image.jpg, and I save it to http://API_URL/images/image.jpg, I want that jpg to be accessible only after I receive a validation token from that user, but that isn't possible since the image will be accessed via , i.e. not a get or post where I can attach such token. Is that something I should be doing via the express router? Maybe make the path of the saved file /images/:id and then attach some long user id which cannot be guessed as part of the path to get to the image?

Thanks

Comment: you can specify these routes like '*.jpg' and add an authentication middleware to that route

Comment: But then how do I pass a token from the client side to access the link if I access it via <img src= ... >

Comment: fetch image via ajax convert to blob url and then display the image. If you are worried about auth on images this is a way to do if you don't want to send tokens via get query params,